# Did I write right queries to database with inheritance?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ef-model-first

I am learning EF and Model First approach. I have a table, which has inheritance.

Here it is my EDM scheme: http://gyazo.com/fbec21b5fbfc47dd76ff3eaa38f86d36.png

I am not sure about my queries, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE. Am i right?

```
    private static void AddNewEmployee()
    {
        using (EmployeesModelContainer context = new EmployeesModelContainer())
        {
            Employee newEmployee = new Employee
            {
                Name = "Вася",
                Surname = "Пупкин",
                Age = 34,
                Sex = Sex.Man,
                ProfessionId = 4,
                EducationLevelId = 1
            };

            context.Persons.Add(newEmployee);

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    private static void UpdateEmployee()
    {
        using (EmployeesModelContainer context = new EmployeesModelContainer())
        {
            var updateEmployeeQuery = (from employee in context.Persons.OfType<Employee>()
                                       where employee.Name == "Вася"
                                       select employee).FirstOrDefault();

            updateEmployeeQuery.Age = 39;
            updateEmployeeQuery.EducationLevelId = 2;

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    private static void DeleteEmployee()
    {
        using (EmployeesModelContainer context = new EmployeesModelContainer())
        {
            var deleteEmployeeQuery = (from employee in context.Persons.OfType<Employee>()
                                       where employee.Name == "Вася"
                                       select employee).FirstOrDefault();

            context.Persons.Remove(deleteEmployeeQuery);

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

The question is, If I need to **add** or **delete** some data in **Employees** table, why i am adding or deleting in **Person** table and it is allright? Data adding in **Person** and in **Employees** tables. And if I **Updating** some data in **Employees** table, why the data is updating in **Person** table correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. You can add an `Employee` to the `Persons` table, both the `Employee` table and `Persons` table will be inserted into. Likewise, adding a `Person` to the `Person` table does not touch the `Employee` table.

To query, you use `context.Persons.OfType<Employee>()`